# Generate Scripts in SQL Server (big files)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in process of moving my database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008. Since I can't just restore them like if I was moving from 2008 to 2012 I have to use generate scripts for data and schemas.

Problem is I have some HUGE database files. One of the files generate becomes 19gb. There does not seem to be any way to move this file because I think the size itself makes the file corrupt. I cant open the file in the SQL Server Management Studio and even using the `.bat` script it fails (it just freezes). My other tables I have no problem with but they are much much smaller.

What could fix this would be if there was a way to split the data up in several files like each file is 100mb or whatever, then I could make a script that would execute them all, but is this possible?

If not what do you guys suggest?

Comment: What are you using to export the data into these huge files? Maybe BCP?  You can't just use the import/export wizard built into SSMS to copy from 2012 to 2008?

Comment: Try using copy database wizard.

Comment: if the problem is single table data then write a query to generate scripts then you can specify the row number say 1-1000000 then next set like wise then save in separate files and apply those in 2008 db

Comment: I would suggest "Generate scripts" for all small-medium tables and bcp for big.

Comment: Im mostly selftaught in SQL. what is BCP?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a database with the same name in SQL Server 2008 (and possibly tables) and try to do a replication between the two database with SQL Server 2008 as the subscriber, just once should do

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability, you could also try creating a linked server entry on the 2008 box that points to the 2012 one. Then, you can use the four part fully qualified name (`server.database.schema.table`) to `SELECT` the rows from the 2012 instance and `INSERT` them into the 2008 instance.

Comment: I dont have this ability becuase they are on different machines and I have no idea how to do this

Comment: As long as the two machines can communicate, the linked server will work. A quick Google search took me to this MSDN page: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782(v=sql.105).aspx) that explains how to create a linked server.